# How to send an email without UI in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, email

I am writing a code to send crash report on crash. I need a way to email the crash log file without the involvement of User interface. Is there any way to send the log without the involving of user interface. Actually there is problem while sending crash log from app delegate using presentviewcontroller.

I searched it but all those says to send the crash log on my own server. I think there are two way to send a log report either on the spot when crash occur or after next execution. I searched and found that sending the crash log causes some bad effect on devices so that i leave that one and try to go with second option when i procced with second option there are also two way to manage it, either having mfmailcomposer in appdelegate or during the execution of view controller. Using the second option have a disadvantage over the first one which is we need to check each and every view controller so that i think that sending it via app delegate would be a great idea. Accessing presentviewcontroller from window.rootviewcontroller doesnot give any positive case so that i am searching to manage sending without the involvement of view. In other word it will send crash log without the user's interaction.

Comment: Please search. This has been asked many times.

Comment: You want to send the crash log from user's email account or are you talking about a service where you can send through your own account. Use http://libmailcore.com

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not, at least not without server support. This is by design from Apple.